# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while using csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 4 sparse matrixes with following dimensional:

```
X_train_content_sparse.shape
(62313, 100000)

X_train_title_sparse.shape
(62313, 100000)

X_train_author_sparse.shape
(62313,31540)

X_train_time_features_sparse.shape
(62313, 7)
```

And then I stack arrays in sequence horizontally.

```
X_train_sparse = hstack([X_train_content_sparse, X_train_title_sparse,
                                    X_train_author_sparse, X_train_time_features_sparse])
```

After that I transform this array of sparse matrixes into a sparse matrix.
I apply `csr_matrix(X_train_sparse)` and I receive such error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

```
>X_train_sparse
array([ <62313x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 68519885 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <62313x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 795892 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <62313x31540 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>'
    with 62313 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <62313x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 176241 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

Comment: We'll need to see your full code listing along with the full traceback.

Comment: Are you using `np.hstack` or `sparse.hstack`?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

```
In [83]: M
Out[83]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [84]: np.hstack([M,M])
Out[84]: 
array([<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
In [85]: sparse.csr_matrix(_)
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

That was the wrong `hstack`.  The `np.hstack` knowns nothing about sparse matrices.  So it just wraps each one in `object` array, and joins them into a 2 element array.  So it's not surprising that `csr_matrix` has problems digesting that.

```
In [86]: sparse.hstack([M,M])
Out[86]: 
<10x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 40 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

The `sparse.hstack` converts all matrices into `coo` format, and then joins their `rows,cols,data` arrays appropriately, and then makes a new sparse matrix.

`sparse.hstack` with `format` parameter:

```
In [88]: sparse.hstack([M,M],format='csr')
Out[88]: 
<10x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 40 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: I used `scipy.sparse.hstack` for stacking, not numpy.
Also, I have updated the question descrition

Comment: What you just added is produced by `np.hstack`, just like my `Out[84]`.  `sparse.hstack` produces as sparse matrix, and takes a `format` parameter (see my edit).

Comment: You right. That was actually strange conflict between numpy and scipy functions. I have imported `from scipy.sparse import hstack` in that way, but on default it used numpy's `hstack`. When I changed to `scipy.hstack` it worked fine